# Include a component in CakePHP 2

Tags: model-view-controller, controller, components, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to working with `Security` component in a `Controller` of `CakePHP 2.0` but I'm doing something wrong with it.

I've read in the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html#usage), but when I include the `Security` component in my `Controller` and I call the controller action `register` I get a `blank page`. If I comment the include `public $components = array('Security');` it works again, where I'm wrong?

```
<?php
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
class UsersController extends AppController {
    public $components = array('Security');

    public function register () {
        if (!empty($this->data)) {
            if ($this->data['User']['password'] == $this->data['User']['confirm_password']) {
                $this->User->create();
                $this->User->save($this->data);
                $this->registrationEmail ($this->data['User']['email'], $this->data['User']['username']);
                $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'registration', 'success'));
            }
        }
    }
    private function registrationEmail ($account_email, $username) {
        $email = new CakeEmail('myconfig');
        $email->from(array('mailer@email.com' => 'MySite.com'));
        $email->to($account_email);
        $email->subject('Account activation / MySite.com');
        $email->template('activation');
        // $this->set('activation_code', Security->hash($account_email));
        $email->viewVars(
            array(
                'activation_code' => $this->Security->hash($account_email),
                'username' => $username
            )
        );
        $email->send();
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

How is the registration form rendered in your view file?

If you're using the Security Component, all form fields need to be generated using the FormHelper. In addition you can't fiddle with hidden values on the front end once they've been given a value by the FormHelper.